# Add loading indicator to select menu

Tags: javascript

If I remove `.then(anotherDropdown.remove(0))` I see "Loading..." as the first option as expected but if I put the above line of code back in I never see it. How can I see it and remove it once the fetch call is complete?

```
dropdown.addEventListener('change', function () {
    var id = this.value;

    // set the first option to Loading... when option selected by user
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "Loading...";
    anotherDropdown.add(option, dropdown[0]);




    function getData() {
        fetch(url + id, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(apiData),
                headers: {
                    "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
                }
            })
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            .then(resp => console.log(resp))
             // this line removes the loading message instantly and it is never seen
            .then(anotherDropdown.remove(0))
    }
    getData();
});
```

Comment: No, even in google chrome developer tools if I set my network so slow 3G I can see that it is waiting for data but Loading.. never appears with this line of code present `.then(anotherDropdown.remove(0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.then(anotherDropdown.remove(0))` to `.then(()=>anotherDropdown.remove(0))`

The `.then` accepts a callback function as a parameter.

And it would be better to use [`.finally`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) instead of `.then` for this scenario.

so

```
       fetch(url + id, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(apiData),
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
            }
        })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(resp => console.log(resp))
        .finally(() => anotherDropdown.remove(0))
```